# Pokemon X/Y Hidden Ability Breeding w/o ditto

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

I am attempting to breed an Eevee so that I can get an Espeon with Stored Power. I have a 6IV Eevee that has Stored Power, Baton Pass, and Bold Nature (All desired traits). The problem arises when I attempt to get the Hidden Ability. Everywhere I have read states that it is impossible with two Pokemon that have normal abilities, but never explicitly states that it is impossible with a hidden/normal ability parent combo.

Considering that Stored Power is an egg move and Magic Bounce is a Hidden Ability, how does one go about breeding an Eevee with both? Is it possible in an older generation? Can it be done in gen 6 w/out a ditto using two Pokemon of the same species where one has the hidden ability and the other does not?

Answer (score 5):

You can pass down a hidden ability with a hidden/normal parent combo, but the hidden ability must be on the mother.

A female can pass down the hidden ability when bred with a male of the same egg group (of course includes same species), at an 80% rate.

A male can only pass down the hidden ability if he is bred with a ditto, and has a 60% rate.

[Source](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ability#Abilities_and_breeding)